# What is the difference between a floating point merge and an integer merge?

Tags: algorithm, floating-point, mergesort

In [this paper](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~ogreen3/_docs/GPU%20Merge%20Path%20-%20A%20GPU%20Merging%20Algorithm.pdf), two cases have been considered for comparing algorithms - integers and floating points.

I understand the differences regarding these data types in terms of storage, but am not sure why there is a difference among these.

**Why is there a difference in performance between the following two cases**

- Using merge sort on Integers
- Using merge sort on Floating Points

I understand that it comes down to speed comparison in both the cases, the question is why these speeds might be different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paper states, in section 4, “Conclusion”, “the execution time for merging integers on the CPU is 2.5X faster than the execution time for floating point on the CPU”. This large a difference is surprising on the Intel Nehalem Xeon E5530 used in the measurements. However, the paper does not give information about source code, specific instructions or processor features used in the merge, compiler version, or other tools used. If the processor is used efficiently, there should be only very minor differences in the performance of an integer merge versus a floating-point merge. Thus, it seems likely that the floating-point code used in the test was inefficient and is an indicator of poor tools used rather than any shortcoming of the processor.

Answer (score 0):

Merge sort has an inner loop of quite a bit of instructions. Comparing floats might be a little more expensive but only by 1-2 cycles. You will not notice the difference of that among the much bigger amount of merge code.

Comparing floats is hardware accelerated and fast compared to everything else you are doing in that algorithm.

Also, the comparison likely can overlap other instructions so the difference in wall-clock time might be exactly zero (or not).